# python - Iterator which duplicates elements of iterable object

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I need to write a function `duplicate(it)` which returns iterator duplicating elements of iterable `it`. Examlpe: If `it = [1, 2, 3]` then `list(duplicate(it)) == [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`. I tried to implement `DoubleIterator` class and `duplicate(it)` function for lists (not sure about right way of implementation of `DoubleIterator` in this case, so useful advices are welcome):

```
class DoubleIterator():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.pos = 0
        self.limit = len(data)
        self.dup = 0

    def next(self): # __next__ for Python 3
        if self.dup != 0 and self.dup % 2 == 0:
            self.pos = self.pos + 1
        if self.pos < self.limit:
            self.dup += 1
            return self.data[self.pos]
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

def duplicate(it):
    itr = DoubleIterator(it)
    return iter(itr)
```

It works fine for `list(duplicate(it)) == [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` example and something like:

```
dup = duplicate([1, 2, 3])
print next(dup) #1
print next(dup) #1
print next(dup) #2
print next(dup) #2
print next(dup) #3
print next(dup) #3
```

But one of the tests in task for this fucntion is `dup = duplicate(iter([1, 2, 3]))`and it gives an error: `TypeError: object of type 'listiterator' has no len()`. How should I implement `duplicate` function and iterator class in proper way?

Comment: Why are you even concerned about `limit` here or accessing elements by index? For each element in `self.data` just yield it N many times - you don't need to know/care about its length or even if it has one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overcomplicated things a bit. All you need to do is get the next element and yield that twice.  You do need to treat the input as an iterator, not as a sequence. Only sequences like lists have a length and can be indexed, all an iterator can do is give you the next value until it is exhausted.

For a class-based iterator, that means you need to store the element to be repeated so that every other call to `next()` can produce that stored value, while the other calls get the next element from the input iterator:

```
class DoubleIterator:
    _sentinel = object()

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._data = iter(iterator)
        self._repeat = self._sentinel

    def next(self): # __next__ for Python 3
        if self._repeat is self._sentinel:
            # get next element to yield, can raise StopIteration
            self._repeat = next(self._data)
            return self._repeat
        # repeat last element
        element = self._repeat
        self._repeat = self._sentinel
        return element

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

I used a unique sentinel to make sure that `None` values in the input iterator are supported, and I called `iter()` on the input iterable to make sure we can always call `next()` on that object.

However, it is *much easier* to just write a generator function here, and yield each element twice:

```
def double_iterator(iterator):
    for elem in iterator:
        yield elem
        yield elem
```

You can generalise that further with a loop, but if you only ever need to double the elements, I'd just stick to the simpler double `yield`.

Comment: Or even: `yield from (el for el in iterator for _ in range(2))`... then you can generalise the function if needs be...

Comment: @JonClements: `yield from` is overkill when you could just use `return (el for el in iterator for _ in range(2))`.

Comment: Indeed... instances will both be a `generator` instance, but I was keeping the `yield from` to avoid introducing something that looks completely different than what the OP has been working with...

Comment: you can make it even shorter (and faster) with `... for _ in (1,2)`

Comment: @VPfB: I think the point of using `range()` is to have an easy path towards not having to hard-code the desired repetitions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I know. But in some rare cases I like and prefer the readability of explicitly named iteration rounds. This looked to me like one of those cases.

Answer (score 4):

I would just do it as a generator

```
def duplicate(it,n=2):
    for x in it:
        for _ in range(n):
            yield x
```